# Laravel Roles without pivot table

Tags: php, laravel

I am student and i am new with Laravel and i have this UserController which used to assign multi Roles to User (using pivot table user_role) but i want to assign one role to each user (without pivot table) so i added role_id foreign in table user but i dont know what to change in UserController file.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use App\Role;
use DB;
use Hash;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $data = User::orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(5);
        return view('users.index',compact('data'))
            ->with('i', ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $roles = Role::pluck('display_name','id');
        return view('users.create',compact('roles'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
            'password' => 'required|same:confirm-password',
            'roles' => 'required'
        ]);

        $input = $request->all();
        $input['password'] = Hash::make($input['password']);

        $user = User::create($input);
        foreach ($request->input('roles') as $key => $value) {
            $user->attachRole($value);
        }

        return redirect()->route('users.index')
                        ->with('success','User created successfully');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);
        return view('users.show',compact('user'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);
        $roles = Role::pluck('display_name','id');
        $userRole = $user->roles->pluck('id','id')->toArray();

        return view('users.edit',compact('user','roles','userRole'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$id,
            'password' => 'same:confirm-password',
            'roles' => 'required'
        ]);

        $input = $request->all();
        if(!empty($input['password'])){ 
            $input['password'] = Hash::make($input['password']);
        }else{
            $input = array_except($input,array('password'));    
        }

        $user = User::find($id);
        $user->update($input);
        DB::table('role_user')->where('user_id',$id)->delete();


        foreach ($request->input('roles') as $key => $value) {
            $user->attachRole($value);
        }

        return redirect()->route('users.index')
                        ->with('success','User updated successfully');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        User::find($id)->delete();
        return redirect()->route('users.index')
                        ->with('success','User deleted successfully');
    }
}
```

and you can find all the code here:
http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-52-user-acl-roles-and-permissions-with-middleware-using-entrust-from-scratch-tutorialexample.html

this mean so much to me if you help me and thanks.

Comment: `'roles' => 'required'` will no longer be required but `role_id` will be `required|exists:roles` so you will need to update your user creation and updating pages accordingly.

Comment: thanks, but for this: 
    foreach ($request->input('roles') as $key => $value) {
                $user->attachRole($value);
            }

Comment: That's no longer required. Just make sure that `role_id` is "fillable" in the model and it should work.